# Postfix - recipient bcc : how to send a copy of incoming mails from outside ( any domain ) and skip from inside ( my own domain )

Tags: postfix

I have a fully working setup of postfix-dovecot-mysql. A few weeks ago I added an 'oversight/archive' function to it. Using '**recipient_bcc_copy**' to save a copy of each incoming mails into some mail-folders. This is working fine! My problem is that: i want to skip bcc when the mail comes from my own source ( domain ) wich identical to destination ( domain ).

For example:

```
any-user@outside.domain.org  -->  any-user@my.domain.org  : OK ( should bcc-ed )
any-user@my.domain.org       -->  any-user@my.domain.org  : SKIP ( do not bcc ! )
```

Is it possible somehow with the specified config?

Comment: Mind the corner case where an email with envelope sender of your domain enters your mail system from outside.

Comment: Leaving the copy-all in place & discarding unwanted duplicates using a global `sieve` rule is an option, giving you flexibility in selecting which copies to keep. You might need to make the bcc-recipient unique using `recipient_delimiter`.